# I parsed URL successfully, having trouble passing the string variable to method C#

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, url, global-variables

I am using this line of code to return the part of the url I need: (ineedthis.aspx)

so if you navigate to whatever.aspx this line of code returns "whatever" as a string:

```
string currentURL = this.Page.ToString().
                  Substring(4, this.Page.ToString().Substring(4).Length - 5);
```

my problem is making currentURL available to the entire page. If I make it global (which do I want to do if I need it rewritten every time a page loads?) using this code:

```
public class Globals
{
    public static string currentURL = 
                 this.Page.ToString().
                    Substring(4, this.Page.ToString().Substring(4).Length - 5);
}
```

the compiler has a problem with keyword `this`.

so I guess my question is this:

- how do I create a string that stores the **"whatever"** part of whatever.aspx and make it accessible throughout my project AND when a page loads it rewrites the string to whatever current page the user is on ?

  oh and go easy in your response, noob here!

Answer (score 3):

`Session` is per user by the way, so be careful with that.

This is not a very time consuming operation. I wouldn't worry about making it static.

```
private string currentUrl;

public string CurrentUrl
{
    get
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.currentUrl))
        {
            string page = this.Page.ToString();
            this.currentUrl = page.Substring(4, page.Substring(4).Length - 5);
        }
        return this.currentUrl;
    }
}
```

I would have some inheritance setup:

```
public class MyPage : Page
{
    private string currentUrl;

    public string CurrentUrl
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.currentUrl))
            {
                string page = this.Page.ToString();
                this.currentUrl = page.Substring(4, page.Substring(4).Length - 5);
            }
            return this.currentUrl;
        }
    }

}
```

Then your pages:

```
public class HomePage : MyPage
{
    public void method()
    {
        Console.Write(this.CurrentUrl);
    }
}
```

Comment: this worked great but i am slightly confused exactly where to put your code. to test it i just slapped your first box of code in the code behind file for the particular page i am testing. but the rest of your reply you have "Then your pages:" which confused me. 

are you suggesting i put your setup in my app code data class file and then use your 3rd block of code on every page?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to help you not just copy and paste the code. But at this point, that might not be a big deal. So I would go with what worked.

Comment: And I appreciate it. That is why I am trying to ask more about what your code does. I just copied and pasted to see if it works, and it does. Now I want to know more.

Comment: so in your example, HomePage is inheriting MyPage?

Comment: Correct, that would give you access to that CurrentUrl property in whatever Page extended MyPage.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287536%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) variable or a [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287606%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) variable.

```
ViewState["currentURL"] = currentURL;
```

or

```
Session["currentURL"] = currentURL;
```

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like you should be storing it in a session variable.

```
session["currentURL"] = this.Page.ToString().Substring(4, this.Page.ToString().Substring(4).Length - 5);
```

Depending on what you're planning on doing, anyways.  You'll need to elaborate if you're looking for something different.